# problem similar to random walk problems

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a particle that moves along the set of integers in the following manner. If it is presently
at i, then it next moves to i+1 with probability p and to i-1 with probability 1-p. Starting at 0, let a
denote the probability that it ever reaches 1.

show that
$$ a=p+(1-p)a^2$$
I think problem is just modification of random walk problems

I found the ''a '' as follows but ı can not convert it to above equation. Can someone help to find my mistakes or above equation ?
$$
a=f_{01}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty f_{01} (m)=p+(1-p)p^2+2*(1-p)^2p^3+3(1-p)^3p^4.....
$$

Comment: Are you sure there are only 3 ways to go from 0 to the first occurence of 1 in exactly 7 moves?  Consider: LRLLRRR, LRLRLRR, LLLRRRR, LLRLRRR

Comment: The suggested method for calculating $a$ is easier:  You can justify the equation $a = p+(1-p)a^2$ by thinking recursively and/or using the law of total probability to get:  $$P[visit]=P[visit|\mbox{first jump right}]p+P[visit|\mbox{first jump left}](1-p)$$

Comment: You can safely say that this is a 1-dimensional random walk.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

This is a non-symetric, 1-dimensional random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Firts notice that $a$ is the probability of ever reaching $k+1$ whenever starting from $k$.

Starting from $0$ you can reach $1$ in two distinct ways. First, you can go straight to $1$, this has probability $p$. Or, you can first go to $-1$ (with probability $1-p$), then eventually reach $0$ (with probability $a$, see above with $k=-1$) and then, starting in $0$, eventually reaching $1$ (again with probability $a$). As the steps are independent you may multiply the probabilities and write
$$
a=p+(1-p)\,a^2.
$$